# SpriteKit physicsBody: set up collision but don't 'push' object

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I have a game I am testing, it is a vertical game that detects motion for left and right movement. I am trying to stop the 'player' node from going off the side of the screen. I have set up the physicsBody but the problem is, when the player hits the block at the edge of the screen it is pushing the block and just moving it off screen. What I need is for it to just hit the block, maybe even bounce a little but most importantly I just need it to stop the player sprite going off screen.

Code for the player:

```
player.zPosition = 10

        player.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.1, y: size.height * 0.5)

        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Airplane"), size: CGSize(width: player.size.width, height: player.size.height))

        player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        player.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BodyType.player.rawValue
        player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.score.rawValue
        player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = BodyType.dontCollide.rawValue

        addChild(player)
```

Code for the edge 'block':

```
func sideRestraints() {

        var leftSide:SKSpriteNode!

        leftSide = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "block")
        leftSide.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
        leftSide.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        leftSide.size = CGSize(width: 10, height: frame.size.height)
        leftSide.zPosition = 2;

        leftSide.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: leftSide.size.width, height: leftSide.size.height))
        leftSide.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        leftSide.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = BodyType.player.rawValue
        leftSide.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BodyType.sides.rawValue
        leftSide.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.player.rawValue

        addChild(leftSide)

    }
```

The bodyType structure:

```
enum BodyType:UInt32 {

    case player = 1
    case score = 2
    case dontCollide = 4
    case sides = 8

}
```

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try leftSide.physicsBody!.dynamic = false

Comment: That works in terms of the block not being pushed but now the player just goes over the top of it and off the screen as if it wasnt there

Comment: Can you show yout bodytype structure?

Comment: Sure, I have edited that in now

Comment: you must change collision of player -> player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = BodyType. sides.rawValue

Comment: Thank you, I can see that this helps in terms of the player object is showing that it is hitting the side but it still allows to go off screen, any ideas?

Comment: are you moving the player with pulse or with moveByX action?

Comment: Sorry Simone just seen that - I am using moveByX - is that causing the issue?

Comment: sure, moveby force the physics, try to apply an impulse

Comment: Ok, I think I am following - how would one go about implementing that, currently I am doing let action = SKAction.moveTo(x: destX, duration: 0.2) - sorry, forgive me I am learning as I go along here!